# Executing the file loops infinitely but the assembler did not report any errors

Tags: assembly, x86-16, masm

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA
    
    ARRAY DB 1,9,8,3,4,7

.CODE
    MAIN PROC
        MOV AX,@DATA
        MOV DS,AX

        MOV SI,OFFSET ARRAY
        MOV CX,6
        MOV BL, [SI]

        LOOPX:
            CMP [SI], BL
            JGE UPDATE
            RESUME:
            INC SI
            LOOP LOOPX

            ADD BL,51
            MOV DL,BL
            MOV AH,2

            UPDATE:
            MOV BL,[SI]
            JMP RESUME
    MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

I want to read the largest number in the array.

Comment: After `mov ah, 2` where is the control flow supposed to continue to? Where will it actually go?

Comment: If the assembler had reported any errors, you wouldn't have a program to run at all.  In assembly language, the assembler has zero involvement in checking your program for sanity.  Functions and loops are totally up to you to get right.  Single-step your code in a debugger to see what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

### The program is incomplete

- With `MOV DL,BL` `MOV AH,2` you have setup for using the DOS.PrintCharacter function 02h, but you forgot to actually invoke it. Just add `int 21h`.
- You forgot to end the program! You have allowed the code to fall-through into *UPDATE* where a jump to *RESUME* will create an infinite loop. Use the DOS.Terminate function 4Ch.

### The program has an error/typo

To convert the single digit number into a printable character you need to add **48**, so `ADD BL,51` is wrong.

### The program is not optimal

- The first array element gets compared to itself and triggers a redundant reload of BL. In your array with **6** elements, this code needs **5** comparisons to arrive at the result.
- Because you want to output the result through the DL register, it would be better to use DL from the start.
- Unless you program for the 8086, it would be better to replace `loop ...` by `dec cx` `jnz ...`

  ```
      MOV  SI, OFFSET ARRAY
      MOV  CX, 6 - 1   ; 5 comparisons
      MOV  DL, [SI]    ; First element
    LOOPX:
      INC  SI
      CMP  [SI], DL
      JLE  DONTUPDATE
      MOV  DL, [SI]
    DONTUPDATE:
      DEC  CX
      JNZ  LOOPX

      ADD  DL, 48      ; You could write this as   ADD DL, '0'
      MOV  AH, 02h
      INT  21h

      MOV  AX, 4C00h
      INT  21h
  ```